# How to prevent spam on a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, spam-prevention

I have a simple form that users use to register their email address for a newsletter.

I want to prevent spammers submitting 000's of fake emails. What's the best way to do this?

I thought about limiting the number of inputs from each IP address to, say, 60 per hour, but then thought anyone determined will simply spoof their IP as part of the attack.

Any ideas?

***EDIT: I am looking for a server-side solution. In this situation, UX is important so I don't want to use a captcha, or ask the user to validate with a token**

Comment: How do you know its a fake?

Comment: Well when they type their email in, send the person an email where they have to follow the link in the email to activate it?

Comment: set cookies, set unique id (=token) on each request into form (=hidden field with token), limit the submission of forms to a specific domain, remember user-agents (=Browser+version) (shouldn't change between calls), install honeypots ... even if annoying ... add captchas or "human" ... solvable questions like what is 1+3? ... also you could (at least) try to validate entered e-mails with contacting "their" server ... you could opt-in (-out), so if an e-mail is not veryfied within 24h, it's not valid.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I am considering the scenario where I get 000's of registrations in a few minutes from the same script someone is running

Comment: Train a neural network to look at some inputs(ip, mac address, email ingredients, even the email sending frequency pattern) and give output as 0 or 1 to indicate spamming. Because they may attack from different addresses or different times or different(randomized) emails

Comment: The question isn't really:"How to prevent spam on a form?",it's:"How to prevent people inserting fake emails on the form?" Which would be: Filter_Validate_Email like the answers down here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
function validEmail($email){
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        list($user,$domain) = explode('@',$email);
        return checkdnsrr($domain, 'MX');
    } 
    return false;
}
```

it may not pick up every fake email, but I always validate their email by sending them a validation email with a link.

EDIT:

As for spam on a form use CSRF, that should prevent most spam (at least in my experience)

Comment: Thanks, two quick questions: what does your script do (does it look up dns records?), and what is CSRF?

Comment: @alias51 Hey, so it firsts checks the email to see if it looks correct, it then splits it into the username and the domain.. e.g. Aaran | Google.com, it then checks Googles DNS settings for a mail server and returns true or false based on the results...

CSRF is a random string put into a session that changes each page you visit, you then have a hidden field on your forum and check it on submission, that way a spam bot first has to get that string before posting your form.

Comment: Do you have an example implementation of this?

Comment: @alias51 I tend to use a class in my code so I can't copy it all out but this give a general idea of what needs doing.. http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries

Answer (score 1):

You could use `negative captcha`. Idea is to have a field in the form that is not visible to humans but bots would enter values in it. On server side you can ignore requests that have a value in the negative captcha field.

Adavatage is that normal users do not see any extra steps like enter captcha words or validate the email. Cons is that the method works as long as people would not customize bots specifically for your site.

Example of a negative captcha. Include this in your form.

```
<div style="position: absolute; left:-2000px;"><input type="text" name="email_name" value="" /></div>
```

On server side do somethig like

```
if (params[:email_name] != "") //bot
else //not a bot
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a great technique somewhere on the interwebs. I enhanced it, and it is now available (open source) at www.formspammertrap.com .

It uses some javascript to replace the form action, and requires actual 'clickage' of a live user.

No captchas, hidden fields, etc.; those might work temporarily, but usually doesn't work long-term.

It is free, and it works great on any site I put it on. PHP-based, but will also work in WordPress (not a plugin).

Answer (score 0):

When a user types their email address into the bar, run a script that sends them an email to the address specified that contains a link, when they click the link it will activate that email address for newsletters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use capthcha - which is broken and annoying to users.

What I use is a simple question (how many logs does a dog have) and then use the input of `<input type='text' name='email2' value=''>`. I then do the necessary checks on the server-side of things. But one thing I do not do is to notify the person that something was wrong i.e. invalid number entered in the email2 textbox.

Anyway, just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is, to add another textfield to the `form`-section. In your stylesheet (not the style-tag!), you set its css-property to `display:none`, since most spambots fillout every available `input`-element, but doesn’t load external .css-files.
When your script gets the request, you check this hidden textfield – if it’s blank, you have good chances that this wasn’t spam.